# Broken link on Candidates Search access

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

Reproduce:

Go to Careers, Click on Employers. ( http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer )

Click on Candidate Search ( http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-search )

Link on "try search now" it's broken.

Link points to: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/%24link

> [image: See the link]

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I skipped the first few steps and went directly to the `about-search` URL... The link is still broken though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for this report; I'll fix it up.  In the meantime, I think all the other links to trial search work, or you can just click [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search).